Is it necessary to cite all publications with erroneous interpretations in a PhD thesis?
In my PhD thesis, the main topic is to justify that a philosopher P claims that x = a, but a (very) large number of publications assert that x = b, even though their research doesn’t directly deal with the question of "what x means for P". My question is: Do I need to cite all these publications that adopt the x = b interpretation, even if they only do so indirectly?
Or would it be enough to cite the most relevant works that engage with this issue more directly?

For my own curiosity, is there some reason you believe you might even consider referencing all such publications rather than a representative handful? I doubt that that would have ever crossed my mind.

@Aruralreader Well, I want to armor myself in the defense of the thesis. I do not want to be told that I “forgot” to cite this and that publication, especially when the “most representative” can be a somewhat subjective term.

@Ian Are you claiming to cite the "most representative" paper? Why not just go for something like "a number of publications assert that x=b, for example (list of maybe 3 references)"?

@Ian, in that case I think this is a great learning experience for you. If someone says ‘You forgot to include ABC,’ you simply thank him or her and acknowledge you carefully selected representatives of the ‘x = b’ camp. Diplomacy.

@Anyon Question: Would that be sufficient for the purposes of the thesis? Would it be enough to cite some of those publications for the thesis to be justified?

@Ian What does your advisor think? This is what they are there for.

@Aruralreader Fair enough!

@BryanKrause As I don't have the availability to talk to him and her (they are two) continuously, this doubt hasn't been resolved yet, and I want to have it somewhat outlined before submitting the chapter for correction.

You need to cite what you use in general. However, for a doctoral thesis, it is probably better to cite, in some way, perhaps with a specialized bibliography the papers you are concerned with. This is just to convince those judging the thesis that you have completely covered the ground. Over citation (within reason) is probably better than under citation.
That would be my advice as your advisor, but your advisers opinion is the one that should be followed for a question like this.
And citing "all" such papers may be impossible as you would find it hard to make that claim that you have found them "all".

Thanks, what you answered is kind of what I have in mind, so it makes perfect sense.
